# Run multi XPath queries on childs or some XPath queries on whole HTML document? (PHP)

Tags: php, html, dom, xpath

I want to scrape a website using DOM parsing and XPath. The HTML page has 128 results.

Is it better to run one XPath query on whole HTML and then run many XPath queries on results:

```
$video_urls = $xpath->query('//div[contains(@class, "vid")]/a/@href');
foreach($videos as $video) {
    $video_url = $xpath->query('./a/@href', $video)->item(0)->nodeValue;
    $thumb = $xpath->query('./a/img/@src', $video)->item(0)->nodeValue;
    $title = $xpath->query('./a/img/@alt', $video)->item(0)->nodeValue;
}
```

Or run 4 XPath queries on the whole HTML:

```
$videos = $xpath->query('//div[contains(@class, "vid")]');
$video_urls = $xpath->query('//div[contains(@class, "vid")]/a/@href');
$thumbs = $xpath->query('//div[contains(@class, "vid")]/a/img/@src');
$titles = $xpath->query('//div[contains(@class, "vid")]/a/img/@alt');
```

Comment: Measure it. Make a decision after you have real information. Additionally try fetching the string values directly with: `$video_url = $xpath->evaluate('string(./a/@href)', $video);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Querying the DOM less often as shown in the second example should be faster. But this does not mean much and, ultimately, it depends on your requirements. I would suspect that the real word execution time does not differ much, does it?

However, guessing from your sample, this approach has a catch: It is assumed that all four queries have the same number of results and that a given index in an array holds information scrapped from the same DOM element when you later iterate over them. 
If this is not always the case this will lead to all sorts of confusions.

The first approach arguably is easier to grasp, and is likely less error-prone, but comes with a performance penalty - does it matter?